# What iphone barcode sdk are available that scans multiple simultaneous 1D barcodes

Tags: ios, avfoundation, barcode, barcode-scanner

I was using zbar but it breaks in iOS 10, zxing don't scan multiples

What are you guys using to do this in iOS 10?

Comment: Such questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

iOS does have an API to scan 1D and 2D barcodes. But unfortunately we cannot scan multiple 1D barcodes. However we can still scan multiple 2D barcodes.

Check out [AV Foundation iOS Machine Readable Code Detection FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2325/_index.html) for more details.

> Can AVCaptureMetadataOutput detect multiple 1-Dimensional barcodes in a frame?
>
> No. Only a single 1-dimensional code will be returned with each call to 
>   AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectDelegate
>   captureOutput:didOutputMetadataObjects:fromConnection:, and it will
>   correspond to the center-most decodable barcode in the rectOfInterest.

To answer your question we do have some third party bar code scanning library which can scan multiple barcodes. Below is the app/SDK which i have used personally.

- [Scandit](http://www.scandit.com/developers/)